# Connection to hana DB through PHP/Python with Hdbuserstore

Tags: python, php, sqlalchemy, hana, hdbcli

I'm using PHP to execute a Python script that connects to a Hana DB:

When using the full connection string, data retrieval from the DB works fine:

```
engine_hana = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'hana+hdbcli://{user}:{quoted_password}@{host}:{port}/{tenant}', echo=False)
```

Now, I'm attempting to utilize `hdbuserstore` to connect to the DB in order to conceal connection information using this connection string:

```
engine_hana = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'hana+hdbcli://userkey={KEY}/{TENANT}', echo=False)
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

> (hdbcli.dbapi.Error) (-10104, 'Invalid value for KEY "XXX", directory search path: /var/www/.hdb/')

To connect to `hana` database with `hdbuserstore` mechanism

Comment: CAn you check if the user key (XXX in your error message) you are trying to use actually exists in the Hana database's hdbuserstore? he default location for the userstore is $HOME/.hdb. Ensure that your script is executed by the user who has the correct .hdb directory in their home directory. The error suggests it's looking in /var/www/.hdb/, which is unusual unless your script is running under a web server user like www-data. Double-check the syntax for using hdbuserstore with SQLAlchemy. It should follow the format: hana+hdbcli://@userkey?KEY=YourKey.